can I use boost::intrusive::rbtree with stateful_value_traits?
I saw the example boost::intrusive doc_stateful_value_traits (see below). I need a custome rbtree with stateful_value_traits just like that.
I've tried but failed. rbtree_algorithms.hpp use node_traits with NodeTraits::get_parent.
How to do?
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// (C) Copyright Ion Gaztanaga  2007-2013
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
//    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
//          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
// See http://www.boost.org/libs/intrusive for documentation.
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//[doc_stateful_value_traits
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

//This type is not modifiable so we can't store hooks or custom nodes
typedef int identifier_t;

//This value traits will associate elements from an array of identifiers with
//elements of an array of nodes. The element i of the value array will use the
//node i of the node array:
struct stateful_value_traits
{
   typedef list_node_traits<void*>           node_traits;
   typedef node_traits::node                 node;
   typedef node *                            node_ptr;
   typedef const node *                      const_node_ptr;
   typedef identifier_t                      value_type;
   typedef identifier_t *                    pointer;
   typedef const identifier_t *              const_pointer;
   static const link_mode_type link_mode =   normal_link;

   stateful_value_traits(pointer ids, node_ptr node_array)
      :  ids_(ids),  nodes_(node_array)
   {}

   ///Note: non static functions!
   node_ptr to_node_ptr (value_type &value) const
      {  return this->nodes_ + (&value - this->ids_); }
   const_node_ptr to_node_ptr (const value_type &value) const
      {  return this->nodes_ + (&value - this->ids_); }
   pointer to_value_ptr(node_ptr n) const
      {  return this->ids_ + (n - this->nodes_); }
   const_pointer to_value_ptr(const_node_ptr n) const
      {  return this->ids_ + (n - this->nodes_); }

   private:
   pointer  ids_;
   node_ptr nodes_;
};

int main()
{
   const int NumElements = 100;

   //This is an array of ids that we want to "store"
   identifier_t                  ids   [NumElements];

   //This is an array of nodes that is necessary to form the linked list
   list_node_traits<void*>::node nodes [NumElements];

   //Initialize id objects, each one with a different number
   for(int i = 0; i != NumElements; ++i)   ids[i] = i;

   //Define a list that will "link" identifiers using external nodes
   typedef list<identifier_t, value_traits<stateful_value_traits> > List;

   //This list will store ids without modifying identifier_t instances
   //Stateful value traits must be explicitly passed in the constructor.
   List  my_list (stateful_value_traits (ids, nodes));

   //Insert ids in reverse order in the list
   for(identifier_t * it(&ids[0]), *itend(&ids[NumElements]); it != itend; ++it)
      my_list.push_front(*it);

   //Now test lists
   List::const_iterator   list_it (my_list.cbegin());
   identifier_t *it_val(&ids[NumElements]), *it_rbeg_val(&ids[0]);

   //Test the objects inserted in the base hook list
   for(; it_val != it_rbeg_val; --it_val, ++list_it)
      if(&*list_it  != &it_val[-1])   return 1;

   return 0;
}
//]


Sure. Just make sure you

use rbtree_node_traits instead of list_node_traits
also pass the comparator object to the container's constructor

Here's a modernized version showing both the list and the tree. To make the tests interesting, I reversed the original array of ids, so the tree can be seen ordering its elements in ascending order, just like the list (which is just filled in reverse):
Live On Coliru
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>

#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include <boost/intrusive/rbtree.hpp>

namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

// This type is not modifiable so we can't store hooks or custom nodes
using identifier_t = int;

// This value traits will associate elements from an array of identifiers with
// elements of an array of nodes. The element i of the value array will use the
// node i of the node array:
template <typename NodeTraits> struct stateful_value_traits {
    using node_traits    = NodeTraits;
    using node           = node_traits::node;
    using node_ptr       = node*;
    using const_node_ptr = node const*;
    using value_type     = identifier_t;
    using pointer        = identifier_t*;
    using const_pointer  = identifier_t const*;

    static constexpr bi::link_mode_type link_mode = bi::normal_link;

    stateful_value_traits(pointer ids, node_ptr node_array) : ids_(ids), nodes_(node_array) {}

    /// Note: non static functions!
    node_ptr       to_node_ptr(value_type& value) const { return this->nodes_ + (&value - this->ids_); }
    const_node_ptr to_node_ptr(value_type const& value) const { return this->nodes_ + (&value - this->ids_); }
    pointer        to_value_ptr(node_ptr n) const { return this->ids_ + (n - this->nodes_); }
    const_pointer  to_value_ptr(const_node_ptr n) const { return this->ids_ + (n - this->nodes_); }

  private:
    pointer  ids_;
    node_ptr nodes_;
};

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
int main() {
    int const NumElements = 100;

    // This is an array of ids that we want to "store"
    identifier_t ids[NumElements];

    // This is an array of nodes that is necessary to form the linked list
    bi::list_node_traits<void*>::node nodes[NumElements];
    bi::rbtree_node_traits<void*>::node tree_nodes[NumElements];

    // Initialize id objects, each one with a different number
    std::ranges::iota(ids, 0);
    std::ranges::reverse(ids);
    fmt::print("ids: {}\n", ids);

    // Define a list that will "link" identifiers using external nodes
    using List = bi::list<                                                  //
        identifier_t,                                                       //
        bi::value_traits<stateful_value_traits<bi::list_node_traits<void*>> //
                         >>;//
    // Define a tree that will "link" identifiers using external nodes
    using Tree = bi::rbtree<                                                  //
        identifier_t,                                                         //
        bi::value_traits<stateful_value_traits<bi::rbtree_node_traits<void*>> //
                         >>;

    // This list will store ids without modifying identifier_t instances
    // Stateful value traits must be explicitly passed in the constructor.
    List my_list({ids, nodes});
    Tree my_tree({}, {ids, tree_nodes});

    // Insert ids in reverse order in the list
    for (identifier_t& id :  ids)
        my_list.push_front(id);
    // Insert ids into the tree
    for (identifier_t& id : ids) {
        auto [it, not_duplicate] = my_tree.insert_unique(id);
        assert(not_duplicate);
    }

    // Now test lists
    assert(std::ranges::equal(ids | std::views::reverse, my_list));
    assert(std::ranges::equal(ids | std::views::reverse, my_tree));
}

Printing the expected output and passing all asserts.
